# How to achieve a translucent background color for the control bar of FlowPlayer?

Tags: flowplayer

I'm trying to style the control bar of the flowplayer and i want a semi-transparent(translucent) black control bar.

When i give an opacity value like this :

```
controls: {
    url: "/flowplayer/flowplayer.controls-3.2.15.swf",
    backgroundColor: "#000000",
    opacity: 0.5
}
```

even the controls within the control bar (the play/pause buttons, seek bar, etc) become translucent. I don't want that to happen. I only want the "background" of the control bar to be trasnlucent.
How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Got it!! All i had to do was

```
backgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,0,0.5)"
```

Silly me!!!